# How to put data-attribute to lower case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div data-answer="   True" class="question-container"></div>
```

With this js:

```
Drupal.behaviors.articleQuiz = (function(){
    var _attach = function(context){
            $('.question-container', context)
            .once()
            .each(function(i, section){
                new ArticleQuiz($(section));
            });
    };

    return {
            attach: _attach
    };
})();

function ArticleQuiz($el){
    this.$el = $el;
    this.$el.data('answer'); // the value of this needs to be lower case
    this.quizLogic();
    return this;
}

ArticleQuiz.prototype.quizLogic = function(){
    var THIS = this;

    $('.quiz-cols a', this.$el)
        .on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $target = $(e.target);

        // exit if choice already made: users can't change their pick
        if (THIS.$el.hasClass('answered')) return;

        $target.addClass('selected');

        THIS
            .$el
            //add correct or incorrect class depending on the selected answer and the correct answer
            .addClass( ($target.data('value') == THIS.answer) ? 'correct':'incorrect' )
            //add the answered class so in the future we know that this question was already answered
            .addClass('answered');
        });

    return THIS;
};
```

The weirdest thing is that in the `console.log` it returns the data-answer attribute in lower case but in the html it still looks like this:

[image]

What can I do?

**NOTE:**
That data-answer value is populated dynamically by a PHP. so the real markup looks like this

```
<div data-answer="<?php print render($content['field_paragraph_answer']); ?>" class="question-container"></div
```

Comment: You will have to change attribute, by using attr()...

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you *want* to do. The reason it's unchanged in the DOM is that you never change it in the DOM. Separately, `$('data-answer')` will return an empty jQuery object, because it looks for elements with that **tag name**, e.g. `<data-answer>...</data-answer>`.  Also, you're never calling `ArticleQuiz` via `new` (or indeed, at all), but you seem to be setting up properties on `this`.

Comment: This is completely normal, the html is not changed by yiur code. It sumply gets the attribute and logs it in lower case. If you want to change the attrebute itself you can use a Jquery function called .attr() or you can use the vanilla JS function called setAttribute(). Tho I'm not sure why you care about the html?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I pasted only the more relevant parts of the code. I thought it was implicit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my changes. There is the whole code.

Comment: Yes, but you always show the **relevant** parts. With your latest edit, though, you've incorporated an answer into the code in the question. That's not how things are done here. Now it looks like the answerer is just telling you to do what you've already done.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my question was so simple. All I need to know is how to put in lower case the value of the data-answer attribute. You are doing big a small thing.

Comment: Not me, mate. How hard is it to read [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com)? Specifically [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)? If that's really all you needed to know, the original question had way too much cruft in it.

Comment: Check my edit.  That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the actual HTML DOM element's attribute in your code, look for the comment below, I set the `.data()` value, but also you have to manually set back the attribute with `attr()` in order to update the HTML.

That part isn't always necessary, because jQuery will keep track of the `data` in the background.  Just if you need it for CSS or jQuery selectors later.

```
function ArticleQuiz($el){
    this.$el = $el;

    //get data('answer') and set to lowercase
    this.answer = this.$el.data('answer').toLowerCase();

    //set data and HTML attributes to lowercase value of this.answer
    this.$el.data('answer', this.answer).attr('data-answer', this.answer);

    this.quizLogic();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.  What is wrong with the OP's code and how does your answer fix it?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?  I've updated my answer with an explanation. I thought the comment was pretty clear.

Comment: You deleted the part of the code where you set `this.answer` in your edit.